# How to go to another php file after the execution of one php file?

Tags: javascript, php, css, html, localhost

I just a Noobie who`s trying to get clear on certatin topics regarding my project. I would like to know if there is a possibility of going to another php file after the execution of current php file. Thanks in Advance :-)

Comment: Did you try `include`?

Comment: Your question is unclear and lacks detail. In what way are you using PHP? Why don't you put the contents of the other file into the one you are already excuting?

Comment: if there is a possibility of going to another php file after the execution of current php file? What action you want to execute?
show your code what you have tried so far and learn [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

on the bootom of the script write

```
header("Location: /foo.php")
```

foo.php is desired page to redirect
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include that file, use this after execution of code:

```
include('file_name.php');
```

If you want to go to another PHP file, use this after execution of code:

```
header('Location:file_name.php');
```